# makefile not working for -std=c++11

Tags: c++11, makefile

The purpose of this program is to read in data and then print out sorted data based on a few criteria.

I can get my program to compile and print out data when entering `g++ -std=c++11 -o testexe assign4.cc amenity.cc` but when I create a make file to do the same thing it gives out these errors:

```
z1755294@hopper:~/assign4$ make
g++  -c amenity.cc
amenity.cc: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Amenity&)’:
amenity.cc:52:21: error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
     am.id = stoi(tmp); // from_string_to< int >(tmp);
                     ^
amenity.cc:61:31: error: ‘stof’ was not declared in this scope
     am.avg_Jan_temp = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
                               ^
amenity.cc: In function ‘float get_avg(const ListFlt&)’:
amenity.cc:176:24: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  { return init += val; });
                        ^
amenity.cc:176:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘accumulate(std::vector<float>::const_iterator, std::vector<float>::const_iterator, double&, get_avg(const ListFlt&)::<lambda(double&, float)>)’
  { return init += val; });
                         ^
amenity.cc:176:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/numeric:62:0,
                 from Amenity.h:10,
                 from amenity.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:146:5: note: template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)
     accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:146:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
amenity.cc: In substitution of ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const float*, std::vector<float> >; _Tp = double; _BinaryOperation = get_avg(const ListFlt&)::<lambda(double&, float)>]’:
amenity.cc:176:25:   required from here
amenity.cc:176:25: error: template argument for ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)’ uses local type ‘get_avg(const ListFlt&)::<lambda(double&, float)>’
  { return init += val; });
                         ^
amenity.cc:176:25: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/numeric:62:0,
                 from Amenity.h:10,
                 from amenity.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:120:5: note: template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp)
     accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:120:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
amenity.cc:176:25: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
  { return init += val; });
                         ^
amenity.cc: In function ‘float get_sd(const ListFlt&, float)’:
amenity.cc:188:44: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
  { return init += (val - avg)*(val - avg); });
                                            ^
amenity.cc:188:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘accumulate(std::vector<float>::const_iterator, std::vector<float>::const_iterator, float&, get_sd(const ListFlt&, float)::<lambda(float&, float)>)’
  { return init += (val - avg)*(val - avg); });
                                             ^
amenity.cc:188:45: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/numeric:62:0,
                 from Amenity.h:10,
                 from amenity.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:146:5: note: template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)
     accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:146:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
amenity.cc: In substitution of ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const float*, std::vector<float> >; _Tp = float; _BinaryOperation = get_sd(const ListFlt&, float)::<lambda(float&, float)>]’:
amenity.cc:188:45:   required from here
amenity.cc:188:45: error: template argument for ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)’ uses local type ‘get_sd(const ListFlt&, float)::<lambda(float&, float)>’
  { return init += (val - avg)*(val - avg); });
                                             ^
amenity.cc:188:45: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp, class _BinaryOperation> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation)’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/numeric:62:0,
                 from Amenity.h:10,
                 from amenity.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:120:5: note: template<class _InputIterator, class _Tp> _Tp std::accumulate(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp)
     accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_numeric.h:120:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
amenity.cc:188:45: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
  { return init += (val - avg)*(val - avg); });
                                             ^
amenity.cc: In function ‘void print_top_bottom_n(ListA&, int, int)’:
amenity.cc:257:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘am’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  for (const auto &am : vecA)
                   ^
amenity.cc:257:24: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
  for (const auto &am : vecA)
                        ^
amenity.cc:262:10: error: no match for call to ‘(PrintIt) (const int&)’
    prt(am);
          ^
In file included from amenity.cc:1:0:
Amenity.h:69:7: note: candidate is:
 class PrintIt
       ^
amenity.cc:195:6: note: void PrintIt::operator()(const Amenity&)
 void PrintIt::operator () (const Amenity& am)
      ^
amenity.cc:195:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const int’ to ‘const Amenity&’
amenity.cc:270:10: error: no match for call to ‘(PrintIt) (const int&)’
    prt(am);
          ^
In file included from amenity.cc:1:0:
Amenity.h:69:7: note: candidate is:
 class PrintIt
       ^
amenity.cc:195:6: note: void PrintIt::operator()(const Amenity&)
 void PrintIt::operator () (const Amenity& am)
      ^
amenity.cc:195:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const int’ to ‘const Amenity&’
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'amenity.o' failed
make: *** [amenity.o] Error 1
```

I have attached my source code and header files.

assign4.cc

```
#include "Amenity.h" //include iostream and string //
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::ifstream;
using std::flush;
using std::cerr;

string takeInString( const string& msg = "" ) 
{
    string val;
    cout << msg << flush;
    getline( cin, val );
    return val;
}

int takeInChr( const string& msg = "" )
{
    string reply = takeInString( msg );
    if( reply.size() )
        return reply[0];
    // else ...
    return 0;
}

bool more() //open more files //
{
    if( tolower( takeInChr( "Do you want to open another file (y/n) ? " )) == 'n' )
        return false;
    // else ...
    return true;
}

bool load_from( const char* fname, ListA& vec )
{
    ifstream fin( fname );
    if( fin )
    {
        Amenity tmp;
        while( fin >> tmp )
            vec.push_back( tmp );
        fin.close();
        return true;
    }
    // else
    cerr << "There was a problem opening file " << fname
              << endl;
    cin.get();
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    do
    {
        string name = takeInString( "Enter file name: " );

        // attempt to find and open file to read it ... //

            ListA vecA;
            if( load_from(name.c_str(), vecA) )
            {
                cout << "There were " << vecA.size()
                      << " records in file " << name
                      << '\n';

                cout << "Setting scores ... " << flush;
                set_scores( vecA );
                cout << "done!\n";

                for( int choice = 1; choice <= 7; ++ choice )
                    print_top_bottom_n( vecA, choice, 10 );
            }  


    }
    while( more() );
}
```

amenity.cc

```
    #include "Amenity.h"

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::istream;
using std::istringstream;
using std::ostream;
using std::accumulate;


const string Amenity::HEADERS[] =
{
    "",
    "Avg January Temperature (F)", "Avg Total January Sunshine (Hours)",
    "Avg July Temperature (F)", "Avg July Humidity (%)",
    "Avg Landform Topo Code 1 to 21", "Area Land Next to Water (%)",
    "Composite Score"
};

// default ctor //
Amenity::Amenity() : id(-1),
avg_Jan_temp(-999), avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun(-999),
avg_Jul_temp(-999), avg_Jul_humidity(-999),
avg_landform_topo_code_1_21(-1), percent_area_next_to_water(-999),
score(0) {}

string Amenity::get_state() const { return state; }
string Amenity::get_county() const { return county; }
float Amenity::get_avg_Jan_temp() const { return avg_Jan_temp; } 
float Amenity::get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun() const { return avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun; }
float Amenity::get_avg_Jul_temp() const { return avg_Jul_temp; }
float Amenity::get_avg_Jul_humidity() const { return avg_Jul_humidity; }
int Amenity::get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21() const { return avg_landform_topo_code_1_21; }
float Amenity::get_percent_area_next_to_water() const { return percent_area_next_to_water; }
float Amenity::get_score() const { return score; }

// definition of overload operator >> for Amenity objects ...
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Amenity& am)
{
    string line;
    getline(is, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        string tmp;
        if (getline(iss, tmp, ',')) // file here is COMMA separated, 22 fields on a line //
        {
            switch (i) // picking off the fields of interest //
            {
            case 0:
                am.id = stoi(tmp); // from_string_to< int >(tmp);
                break;
            case 1:
                am.state = tmp;
                break;
            case 2:
                am.county = tmp;
                break;
            case 3:
                am.avg_Jan_temp = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
                break;
            case 4:
                am.avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
                break;
            case 5:
                am.avg_Jul_temp = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
                break;
            case 6:
                am.avg_Jul_humidity = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
                break;
            case 7:
                am.avg_landform_topo_code_1_21 = stoi(tmp); // from_string_to< int >(tmp);
                break;
            case 8:
                am.percent_area_next_to_water = stof(tmp); // from_string_to< float >(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return is;
}


// definition of overload operator << for Amenity objects ...
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Amenity& am)
{
    return os << am.id << ", " << am.state << ", " << am.county << ", "
        << am.avg_Jan_temp << ", " << am.avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun << ", "
        << am.avg_Jul_temp << ", " << am.avg_Jul_humidity << ", "
        << am.avg_landform_topo_code_1_21 << ", " << am.percent_area_next_to_water;
}



// HIGHER is 'better' ...
bool cmpJanTemp(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return b.get_avg_Jan_temp() < a.get_avg_Jan_temp();
}
bool cmpJanSunHrs(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return b.get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun() < a.get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun();
}

// LOWER is better ...
bool cmpJulTemp(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return a.get_avg_Jul_temp() < b.get_avg_Jul_temp();
}
bool cmpJulHumidity(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return a.get_avg_Jul_humidity() < b.get_avg_Jul_humidity();
}

// HIGHER is 'better' ...
bool cmpTopoCode(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return b.get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21() < a.get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21();
}
bool cmpPartNearWater(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return b.get_percent_area_next_to_water() < a.get_percent_area_next_to_water();
}

bool cmpScore(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b)
{
    return b.get_score() < a.get_score();
}



void fill(ListFlt& vec, const ListA& vecA, int selectCode)
{
    vec.clear();
    ListA::const_iterator it;

    switch (selectCode)
    {
    case 1: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(it->get_avg_Jan_temp());
        break;
    case 2: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(it->get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun());
        break;
    case 3: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(it->get_avg_Jul_temp());
        break;
    case 4: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(it->get_avg_Jul_humidity());
        break;

    case 5: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(it->get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21());
        break;
    case 6: for (it = vecA.begin(); it != vecA.end(); ++it)
        vec.push_back(log(100 * it->get_percent_area_next_to_water()));
        break;
        /*
        case 7: vec.push_back( it->get_score() );
        break;
        */
    }
}


// 1 //
float get_avg(const ListFlt& vecF)
{
    if (vecF.size() < 1) return 0; // prevent divide by zero and ... //

                                   //const double sum = accumulate( vecF.begin(), vecF.end(), 0.0 );

    double init = 0.0;
    const double sum = accumulate(vecF.begin(), vecF.end(), init,
        [](double& init, float val)
    { return init += val; });

    return (float)sum / vecF.size();
}

// 2 //
float get_sd(const ListFlt& vecF, const float avg)
{
    if (vecF.size() < 2) return 0; // prevent divide by zero and ... //
    float init = 0.0;
    float sum_sqs = accumulate(vecF.begin(), vecF.end(), init,
        [avg](float& init, float val)
    { return init += (val - avg)*(val - avg); });

    return sqrt(sum_sqs / (vecF.size() - 1));
}



void PrintIt::operator () (const Amenity& am)
{
    cout << am.get_county() << ' ' << am.get_state() << ' ';
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: cout << am.get_avg_Jan_temp(); break;
    case 2: cout << am.get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun(); break;
    case 3: cout << am.get_avg_Jan_temp(); break;
    case 4: cout << am.get_avg_Jul_humidity(); break;
    case 5: cout << am.get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21(); break;
    case 6: cout << am.get_percent_area_next_to_water(); break;
    case 7: cout << am.get_score(); break;
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

void set_scores(ListA& vecA)
{
    float avgs[6] = { 0 }, sds[6] = { 0 };
    ListFlt vecF;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        fill(vecF, vecA, i + 1);
        avgs[i] = get_avg(vecF);
        sds[i] = get_sd(vecF, avgs[i]);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecA.size(); ++i)
    {
        float sc = 0;
        sc += (vecA[i].get_avg_Jan_temp() - avgs[0]) / sds[0];
        sc += (vecA[i].get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun() - avgs[1]) / sds[1];
        sc += (vecA[i].get_avg_Jul_temp() - avgs[2]) / sds[2];
        sc += (vecA[i].get_avg_Jul_humidity() - avgs[3]) / sds[3];
        sc += (vecA[i].get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21() - avgs[4]) / sds[4];
        sc += (log(100 * vecA[i].get_percent_area_next_to_water()) - avgs[5]) / sds[5];
        vecA[i].set_score(sc);
    }
}


void print_top_bottom_n(ListA& vecA, int choice, int n)
{
    cout << '\n' << Amenity::HEADERS[choice] << '\n';
    cout << string(Amenity::HEADERS[choice].size(), '=') << '\n';

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpJanTemp); break;
    case 2: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpJanSunHrs); break;
    case 3: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpJulTemp); break;
    case 4: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpJulHumidity); break;
    case 5: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpTopoCode); break;
    case 6: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpPartNearWater); break;
    case 7: sort(vecA.begin(), vecA.end(), cmpScore); break;
    }

    int count = 0,
        size = vecA.size();

    PrintIt prt(choice); // call ctor ... //

    for (const auto &am : vecA)
    {
        ++count;
        if (count <= n)
        {
            prt(am);

            if (count == n)
            {
                cout << "...\n";
            }
        }
        else if (count > size - n)
            prt(am);

    }
}
```

Amenity.h

```
#ifndef AMENITY_H
#define AMENITY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> // re. stringstream

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // re. vector sort //
#include <numeric> // re. accumulate //
#include <cmath> // re. sqrt //

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;


class Amenity
{
public:
    Amenity(); // default ctor //

    string get_state() const;
    string get_county() const;
    float get_avg_Jan_temp() const;
    float get_avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun() const;
    float get_avg_Jul_temp() const;
    float get_avg_Jul_humidity() const;
    int get_avg_landform_topo_code_1_21() const;
    float get_percent_area_next_to_water() const;
    float get_score() const;
    void set_score(float sc) { score = sc; }
    static const string HEADERS[];

private:
    int id;
    string state; // 2 chars's //
    string county;
    float avg_Jan_temp;
    float avg_hrs_tot_Jan_sun;
    float avg_Jul_temp;
    float avg_Jul_humidity;
    int avg_landform_topo_code_1_21;
    float percent_area_next_to_water;
    float score;

    // prototype for overload operator >> for Amenity objects ...
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Amenity& am);

    // prototype for overload operator << for Amenity objects ...
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Amenity& am);
};


typedef vector< Amenity > ListA;
typedef vector< float > ListFlt;


bool cmpJanTemp(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpJanSunHrs(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpJulTemp(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpJulHumidity(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpTopoCode(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpPartNearWater(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);
bool cmpScore(const Amenity& a, const Amenity& b);


class PrintIt
{
public:
    PrintIt(int choice = 1) : choice(choice) {}
    void set_choice(int ch) { choice = ch; }
    void operator () (const Amenity& am);
private:
    int choice;
};


void fill(ListFlt& vec, const ListA& vecA, int selectCode = 1);

// 1 //
float get_avg(const ListFlt& vecF);

// 2 //
float get_sd(const ListFlt& vecF, const float avg);


void set_scores(ListA& vecA);
void print_top_bottom_n(ListA& vecA, int choice, int n);

#endif //* AMENITY_H *//
```

Makefile

```
#Assign compiler variables
CC=g++
CCXFLAGS=-std=c++11


#Create object code to executable
myprog: amenity.o assign4.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o amenity.o assign4.o

#Create source code to object code
amenity.o: amenity.cc Amenity.h
        $(CC) $(CLFAGS) -c amenity.cc

assign4.o: assign4.cc Amenity.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c assign4.cc


clean:
        -rm *.o myprog
```

If anyone can help me fix these error and fix my makefile to compile, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: From the make output you can see that it doesn't compile with `-std=c++11`. So the Makefile doesn't do what you want and has an error, not those files you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `CXXFLAGS` in your `Makefile` add `-std=c++11` to it. If not, just put the following at the top of your `Makefile`:

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

Comment: I added what you said to the makefile but still receiving errors.

Comment: Could you update the error log with the errors you are receiving now?

Comment: You have a typo in your `Makefile` - replace `CCXFLAGS` with `CXXFLAGS`. Also, add `$(CXXFLAGS)` to compiler command line after `$(CFLAGS)`.